# TFS 2012 - Product backlog missing future iterations & unable to forecast

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfs-workitem, agile-project-management

I have two questions:

1. According to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee191595%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if I define some future iterations
   (i.e. iterations with dates set in the future) then I should see
   them listed on the left hand side under the heading 'Future'. But I don't see
   anything:

   [image: Product Backlog]
2. I assume this problem is related, but I'm hoping to get the
   forecasting setup as per [this article](http://intovsts.net/2013/08/05/confusion-about-agile-forecasting-in-tfs/), but as shown in the
   screen shot below I'm getting an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are the future iterations checked? 
There is a checkbox next to iterations in Iterations window - see [screenshot](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/image_759F5D2A.png).